# Can I automatically start a task when a folder is opened?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does VS code support starting a gulp-watch task on startup? I'd like to start the watcher when I open the editor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I create an extension that can do it.
It is "Blade Runner". Try this! [Blade Runner on Visual Studio Code Market Place](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/yukidoi.blade-runner)

Comment: Thanks, I'm installing it now.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Good job!

Comment: This only brings up the "run build task" list when opening the folder, so it seems the only thing it does automatically is press Cmd+Shift+B for me... unless I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 38):

This functionality was added in v1.30: [Release notes: run task on folder open](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_run-on-folder-open)

> Run on folder open
>
> If you have a task that you always run when you open a folder, you can
>   configure it to run automatically when that folder is opened by
>   configuring its "`runOn`" property. We found this useful for making sure
>   no one breaks our new strict null checks in the VS Code repository. By
>   adding `"runOn": "folderOpen"`, everyone who allows tasks to be run
>   automatically will get markers when they violate the strict null
>   check:

Example:

```
{
    "type": "npm",
    "script": "strict-null-check-watch",
    "label": "TS - Strict Null Checks",
    "isBackground": true,
    "problemMatcher": {
        "base": "$tsc-watch",
        "owner": "typescript-strict-null",
        "applyTo": "allDocuments"
    },
    "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
{
  "label": "Tasks: copy3",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "gulp",
  "args": [
    "copy3",
    "--file",
    "${fileBasename}"
  ],
  "problemMatcher": [],
  "runOptions": {
    "runOn": "folderOpen"
  }
},
```

Comment: Make sure that automatic tasks are enabled:

1. CTRL-P
2. Search for and run 'Manage Auotomatic Tasks in Folder'
3. Select for and run 'Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder'

Comment: Those are tasks and they go into your `.vscode/tasks.json` file.

Comment: @AndreasVendel It doesn't look like that works for me, do you know if this got deleted?

Comment: All works fine, thanks! I had a similar problem as @AndreasVendel – so double-check the mentioned above 'Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder', but to search for it press "F1" instead of "Ctrl+P" (last command search for files only).

Comment: My comment was not entirely correct. It should have been CTRL-SHIFT-P, but F1 also works, as @OlegZarevennyi suggested.

Comment: After adding the task to tasks.json I think you need to run the task manually one time, and then you'll get a popup saying something like "Would you like to allow this task to run automatically?" That's what I had to do to get it working.

Comment: If you would like to simplify the use of `runOn: folderOpen` inside devcontainers, please vote in this feature request:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6580

Answer (score 5):

This is an old thread, but the question is still up to date. Blade Runner did not suit my needs, nor did any other extension.

I created an extension [AutoLaunch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=philfontaine.autolaunch) that can run a specific task from tasks.json or launch a specific debug configuration from launch.json.

Answer (score 2):

Just as Mark suggested You can use `"runOn": "folderOpen"`, but it's not that simple to run a Gulp task I believe. I suggest trying to do it the following way.

```
{
    "label": "Watch",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "gulp watch",
    "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
    }
)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like that works for me, is there anything else to enable to make that work?

Comment: @Timberman, I think VSCode should ask You about it, but You can try adding manually `"problemMatcher": []` to this object. Maybe that will help. If not, please precise if there are any errors displayed and if so, what are they. Also, I think that there should be no need to restart the whole VSCode to check if Your configuration works - running "Reload window" command (You can find it after pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`) shall be enough.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. This is a good suggestion (ability to run a task on startup), can you please file an issue in the microsoft/vscode repo on GitHub? (Sorry, I can't post more than 2 links yet)?

In the meantime, here are a couple of options:

- You can specify a particular task as a Build task and then press `CMD+SHIFT+B` when you open the folder to start the task. See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_mapping-gulp-grunt-and-jake-output-to-problem-matchers
- You could write an extension that is activated on startup and then runs gulp with the task name. See here for extension activation options: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/activation-events#_activationevents.