# How to use VS Code Integrated Terminal to programmatically run commands

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

When opening a project using `code .` I want the integrated terminal to run a file or script. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal talks about args going into the shell invocation itself, and the workspace settings in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings don't reference anything related to this. But I have a `./.vscode/settings.json` where I can change the colors of the terminal I guess, but that isn't arbitrary bash commands.

How do I get scripts like`gvm pkgset etc;...`  to run on VSCode launch per workspace?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103549/can-i-automatically-start-a-task-when-a-folder-is-opened/53755091#53755091

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that you want to customize the colors of the integrated terminal in VSCode, just open your `settings.json` and add the following entries to overwrite the colors you want to modify:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.ansiBlack": "#50ff00",   //this overwrites black colors with green
    "terminal.ansiBlue": "#ff0000",    //this overwrites blue colors with red
    ...
}
```

So, for example if you want to change the black colors into another one (i.e. green), you'll have to asign `"#50ff00"` to `"terminal.ansiBlack"`. As you see in the screenshot below, there are a lot more colors you can adjust.

Here's how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: I was able to find documentation about this, but specifically looking for how to run arbitrary bash commands in the integrated terminal on vs code start to a specific workspace.

Comment: @[LostOdinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3606679/lost-odinson) Oh, okay then. I must have have misunderstood it.