# How can I fix error highlighting in VSCode terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmder

Whenever the terminal outputs an error, this red highlighting appears and never goes away until I kill the terminal. Is there a way to fix this? I am using cmder and the theme is monokai pro.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4l1D.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can try [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55077651/9110128). It works on Linux but should also work on Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do it. the official discussion here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/243