# How can I change the highlight colour of an error message in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been struggling to read error messages on yellow background with white text (image below). Any ideas, on how can I change the highlight color? I am aware that I need to do in the user settings and this page (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) shows which settings I can change, but there are so many options and I have no idea from the info given which one corresponds to my problem. Thank you!

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9keH.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change error highlight color in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873768/change-error-highlight-color-in-vs-code)

Comment: Did you manage to change the color? Answer and comment by @MayurAgarwal don't seem to work for me.

Comment: This answer to another question solves the issue for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70974277/8303090

Also, see the following answer for other colours shown in the terminal:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71405405/8303090

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `settings.json` in VsCode and then, search for

```
"editor.rangeHighlightBackground":"Color code"
```

and **replace** the **previous color code** to whatever color you want.