# VS code, run gulp task. Value is not accepted. Valid values: "shell"

Tags: visual-studio-code, gulp, task

Here is what I see when try to create a VS code task which should run a gulp task on folder open event. The code I've found on [VS docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_clear-task-terminal)

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103549/can-i-automatically-start-a-task-when-a-folder-is-opened/53755091?noredirect=1#comment105721270_53755091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead we need to wrap this is a tasks object.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Gulp Watch",
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen"
            },
            "command": "cd wp-content/themes/name/ && gulp watch"
        }
    ]
}
```