# vscode settings.json - run background terminal application on startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to run a terminal application in the background when starting vscode?

I have a file synchroniser service I need to run alongside vscode in the same folder.

I am thinking some `settings.json`, but unable to finde anything.

Comment: Could you run this in a task that runs on workspace folderOpen?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53755091/836330

Comment: Need little trick, I will see if it works in my workflow - thanks